# How to merge cells partially along with vertical direction in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe.

| index | Flag | Data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | aaaa |
| 1 | 0 | bbbb |
| 2 | 0 | cccc |
| 3 | 0 | dddd |
| 4 | 1 | eeee |
| 5 | 0 | ffff |
| 6 | 1 | gggg |
| 7 | 1 | hhhh |
| 8 | 1 | iiii |

I would like to get **a vertical Mergedata** which is separated by **Flag 1**.

| index | Flag | Data | Mergedata |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | aaaa | aaaabbbbccccdddd |
| 1 | 0 | bbbb | - |
| 2 | 0 | cccc | - |
| 3 | 0 | dddd | - |
| 4 | 1 | eeee | eeeeffff |
| 5 | 0 | ffff | - |
| 6 | 1 | gggg | gggg |
| 7 | 1 | hhhh | hhhh |
| 8 | 1 | iiii | iiii |

Maybe, I can do it with **FOR LOOP**.

However, I believe that pandas provide more smart solutions than the above.

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

**Postscript01**

Excuse me.
I coudn't get the above result.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

Array01 = np.array([[0, 1, 'aaaa'],
                 [1, 0, 'bbbb'],
                 [2, 0, 'cccc'],
                 [3, 0, 'dddd'],
                 [4, 1, 'eeee'],
                 [5, 0, 'ffff'],
                 [6, 1, 'gggg'],
                 [7, 1, 'hhhh'],
                 [8, 1, 'iiii']])

df = pd.DataFrame(data=Array01,columns=['index', 'Flag', 'Data'])
df.loc[df.Flag==1,'newmerge'] = df.groupby(df.Flag.cumsum())['Data'].sum().values

df
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

We just need `cumsum` Flag to get the `groupby` key

```
df.loc[df.Flag==1,'newmerge'] = df.groupby(df.Flag.cumsum())['Data'].sum().values
df
Out[47]: 
   index  Flag  Data          newmerge
0      0     1  aaaa  aaaabbbbccccdddd
1      1     0  bbbb               NaN
2      2     0  cccc               NaN
3      3     0  dddd               NaN
4      4     1  eeee          eeeeffff
5      5     0  ffff               NaN
6      6     1  gggg              gggg
7      7     1  hhhh              hhhh
8      8     1  iiii              iiii
```

Comment: I couldn't get a result like yours. 
Please see "Postscript01".

Comment: @aaaaa0a what is your output for df.groupby(df.Flag.cumsum())['Data'].sum().values also, do df.Flag=df.Flag.astype(int) before my code

Comment: thanks a lot. I solved this problem with your advice.
and I posted one more question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67655711/how-to-merge-cells-partially-along-with-vertical-direction-in-pandasver02)
I would appreciate it if you suggest some advice.

Comment: @aaaaa0a is this help would you like accept it ?