# How to merge cells partially along with vertical direction in pandas(Ver02)

Tags: python, pandas

I have an advanced question of
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67643620/how-to-merge-cells-partially-along-with-vertical-direction-in-pandas).

I would **vertical partially merge** with pandas folowing dataframe.

| index | Flag | Data | Mergedata |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | aaaa | aaaabbbbccccdddd |
| 1 | 2 | bbbb | - |
| 2 | 0 | cccc | - |
| 3 | 5 | dddd | - |
| 4 | 1 | eeee | eeeeffff |
| 5 | 2 | ffff | - |
| 6 | 1 | gggg | gggg |
| 7 | 1 | hhhh | hhhh |
| 8 | 1 | iiii | iiii |

I want a mergedata separated **Flag=1**, and **Flag colmun includes  various kaind of values**.

If the flag value is only 0 or 1, we can use cumsum() method suggested by [BENY](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7964527/beny) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67643620/how-to-merge-cells-partially-along-with-vertical-direction-in-pandas).

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

Firstly create a boolean mask:

```
mask=df['Flag']==1
```

Finally:

```
df.loc[mask,'Mergedata']=df.groupby(mask.cumsum())['Data'].sum().values
```

Now If you print `df` you will get:

```
    index   Flag    Data    Mergedata
0   0       1       aaaa    aaaabbbbccccdddd
1   1       2       bbbb    NaN
2   2       0       cccc    NaN
3   3       5       dddd    NaN
4   4       1       eeee    eeeeffff
5   5       2       ffff    NaN
6   6       1       gggg    gggg
7   7       1       hhhh    hhhh
8   8       1       iiii    iiii
```

Answer (score 0):

Change a little bit from my pervious post

```
df.loc[df.Flag==1,'newmerge'] = df.groupby(df.Flag.eq(1).cumsum())['Data'].sum().values
```